# python-geoip does not work on python3.4?

Tags: python, geoip, geolite2

I was able to get geolite2 working on python2.7 - but i needed 3.4. I found the instructions for 2.7 on this link: http://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/. Code fragments are also provided.

```
pip install python-geoip
pip install python-geoip-geolite2
>>> from geoip import geolite2
>>> match = geolite2.lookup('17.0.0.1')
>>> match is not None
True
```

So I naturally changed all the pip to pip3 and installed on a fresh VM. There is no error on the code but it does not looup and return values from their db.

```
pip3 install python-geoip
pip3 install python-geoip-geolite2
```

In the 2.7 VM, when I used 3.4, I pointed the geoip lib at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages - no luck either. It however works on 2.7 on the same VM.

What should I need to do to make it to work on 3.4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`python-geoip` does not support Python 3 and has not been updated in two years. Although there is a [pull request](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-geoip/pull/5) to add Python 3 support, I would not expect it to be merged and released any time soon. I would recommend using the [official MaxMind `geoip2` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2) instead.

Comment: Official version is via web service? Also does it need subscription?

Comment: The `geoip2` package supports both the web service and the database as can be seen in [these examples](http://geoip2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#database-example).

Comment: Is 'geoip2' a subscription based service?

Comment: Will geoip2 give ISP or Organization info?

Comment: The `geoip2` package can use both MaxMind paid databases and the same [free GeoLite2 databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) that `python-geoip` uses. ISP/Organization is only in the paid databases.

Answer (score 7):

Install:

```sh
apt install python3-pip
pip3 install maxminddb 
pip3 install maxminddb-geolite2
```

Example use:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8

from geolite2 import geolite2

reader = geolite2.reader()

# google's ip
match = reader.get('172.217.16.163')
if match:
  # print(match)
  if 'country' in match:
    print(match['country']['iso_code'])
  else:
    print(match['continent']['code'])
else:
  print('')
```

Comment: works only by installing ``pip3 install maxminddb-geolite2``

Answer (score 3):

[`python-geoip`](https://pypi.org/project/python-geoip-python3/) with python 3 support (install with `pip` or `pip3`):

```sh
pip3 install python-geoip-python3
```

output:

```sh
Collecting python-geoip-python3
  Downloading python_geoip_python3-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-geoip-python3
Successfully installed python-geoip-python3-1.3
```

for [`geolite2`](https://pypi.org/project/python-geoip-geolite2/):

```sh
pip3 install python-geoip-geolite2
```

output:

```sh
Successfully built python-geoip-geolite2
Installing collected packages: python-geoip-geolite2
Successfully installed python-geoip-geolite2-2015.303
```

example with `test_geoip.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
from geoip import geolite2
import argparse
import json

# Setup commandline arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get IP Geolocation info')
parser.add_argument('--hostname', action="store", dest="hostname", required=True)

# Parse arguments
given_args = parser.parse_args()
hostname = given_args.hostname
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

print("IP address: {0}".format(ip_address))

match = geolite2.lookup(ip_address)

if match is not None:
    print('Country: ',match.country)
    print('Continent: ',match.continent)
    print('Time zone: ', match.timezone)
    print('Location: ', match.location)
```

run:

```sh
python3 test_geoip.py --hostname=amazon.co.uk
```

output:

```sh
IP address: 178.236.7.220
Country:  IE
Continent:  EU
Time zone:  Europe/Dublin
Location:  (53.3478, -6.2597)
```

run again:

```sh
python3 test_geoip.py --hostname=amazon.co.uk
```

output:

```sh
IP address: 54.239.34.171
Country:  US
Continent:  NA
Time zone:  America/Los_Angeles
Location:  (47.6103, -122.3341)
```

Answer (score -1):

To use the maxmind db:

Install:

```
maxminddb 
maxminddb-geolite
```

In your code:

```
from geolite2 import geolite2

match = geolite2.reader()
geoip = match.get('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

Comment: to me it seems the code provided mixes something up as the code-sections `geolite2` import does not seem to belong to the package `maxminddb`? `maxminddb-geolite` was not installable for me though `pipenv` which i suspect might have to do with maxmind changing their licensing policy and no longer offering the geolite-db to unregistered users. note that there is also a pypi-package `geolite2` which does a similar thing, is also provided by maxmind and has `geolite2` defined in the packages top_level.txt.